# How to set ENABLE_BINRELOC for FileZilla build?

Tags: filezilla

I compiled FileZilla using WinGW/MSYS and it runs fine.
Now I want to start it from another location and it fails with this error message:

> Could not find resource files.... You can set the data directory of
>   FileZilla using the '--datadir ' ...

When I run `filezilla.exe --datadir=c:\Temp\data` it complains that datadir option does not exists.

I found that workaround is to downgrade to Filezilla 3.7.3, but if I do it I have to downgrade Wx to 2.8.
Looking at sources there's a copilation flag ENABLE_BINRELOC that controls `--datadir`.

How do I enable it?

Answer (score 0):

I modified `#elif defined __WXMSW__` section of FileZilla.cpp
added line `pathList.Add(wxGetCwd());`

After recompile prompt changed to:

> fzsftp.exe could not be found ... Possible solutions:
>   -Make sure fzsftp.exe is in a directory listed in your PATH environment variable.

I modified PATH.

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Temp\filezilla\src\putty\.libs
```

and [my filezilla compile](https://github.com/alexbuz/filezilla/tree/master/src/interface/.libs) starts ok now from any location.